# ordinal data negatively skewed. Help me :(

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference, spss, descriptive-statistics

I'm working on my masters dissertation. Please help me this is my very first ever quantitative research and my submission deadline is very soon and my brain is literally melting into soup :(

**1- Data skewness and normal distribution**
I have two categorial nominal variables which is gender and Instagram usage frequency, but all the rest of my variables are Likert scale from highly disagree to highly agree.
I've done an initial exploration of my data with SPSS descriptive analysis and all my Likert scale data as well as Instagram usage is negatively skewed.

Now I've done few steps which I don't know if they are correct or not can you please help me?
I first identify outliers in explore and gave them the next value upper or lower whisker of the boxplot. this improved the skewness of my data notably but they were still negative. so I did a reflection to make them positive. I also tried to run Log10, Square Root and reverse methods all didn't improve my data.

**Question 1 -** I don't know if I needed to do all this since my data is ordinal and I'll be using non parametric analysis anyway? should I just go back and use my original set of data or is skewness not ok even for ordinal?

also I done Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk tests which all were significant showing non normal distribution of my data but again I think this should be normal? do I need to do them?

I felt I spent so much time trying to fix my data and I don't know if all this is necessary, please help me which some advice :(

**Question 2 -** to analyse my data I so far have these steps outlined:
1- frequency analysis for the 2 nominal variables
2- descriptive analysis for the ordinal variable
3- Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk (which now I think not needed?)
4- validity and reliability check (which validity check should I use for ordinal variables?)
5- then correlations for non-parametric variables (which ones should I use? I want to explore the relationship between 2 ordinal variables and 1 nominal and 1 ordinal variable.)
Is there any step I missed or should do to improve my analysis?

**LAST QUESTION:** really sorry for the long post but this is the last one :(
each construct I have have many questions under it. before I work on correlation do I calculate the mean for every group of questions that are related and then work with only one variable? if so , should I have done this from beginning when I was analysing descriptive data or just when I do correlations?

Comment: Ordinal scale variable with few distinct levels can't be normally distributed and there is no point to checking whether they are. This isn't a problem. If they are skew, that is just what they are. It's not a problem.

Comment: Are you not entitled to some support from your teachers?

Comment: Why do you call  Instagram usage frequency a nominal variable?